# directories based on the filename and then move the associated files to the correct directories for random name

Tags: linux, bash, pdf

I would like to create a series of directories based on the filename and 
then move the associated files to the correct directories 
the files would be .pdf from a site and i use wget command for download them 
i try to do this for custom name but i can't understand how can i do this
for random name .pdf .... and for example the first 10 pdf files if there are many..

```
wget -r -l1 -A.pdf
cd / /
for file in {ait,anak,pro}*.*; do
dir=${file%%.*}
mkdir -p "$dir"
mv "$file" "$dir
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `*.pdf` to pick up all pdf files in your for loop:

```
for file in *.pdf
do
    dir="${file%%.*}"
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    mv "$file" "$dir"
done
```